# Juniper and GraphQLEnum - unresolved import InputValue

Tags: rust, graphql

I need help with juniper

I've copied this file https://github.com/graphql-rust/juniper/blob/master/juniper/src/tests/model.rs to my project.

But when I `cargo run`, I get:

```bash
error[E0432]: unresolved import `InputValue`
--> src/model.rs:5:10
|
5 | #[derive(GraphQLEnum, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
| 

     ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `InputValue` in the root
```

I added `InputValue` to `main.rs`, then compiler wanted another `use`s. So even with this in `main.rs`:

```rust
use juniper::InputValue;
use juniper::Value;
use juniper::ToInputValue;
use juniper::FromInputValue;
use juniper::Executor;
```

I got:

```sh
error[E0365]: `InputValue` is private, and cannot be reexported
--> src/model.rs:5:10
|
5 | #[derive(GraphQLEnum, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
|          ^^^^^^^^^^^ reexport of private `InputValue`
|
= note: consider declaring type or module `InputValue` with `pub`

error[E0365]: `Value` is private, and cannot be reexported
--> src/model.rs:5:10
|
5 | #[derive(GraphQLEnum, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
|          ^^^^^^^^^^^ reexport of private `Value`
|
= note: consider declaring type or module `Value` with `pub`
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

The code around where the error is pointing is:

```
#[derive(GraphQLEnum, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[graphql(_internal)]
pub enum Episode {
    #[graphql(name = "NEW_HOPE")] NewHope,
    Empire,
    Jedi,
}
```

It looks like you copied everything including the `#[graphql(_internal)]` attribute. Judging by the name, this is intended to be used only internally within the juniper test suite and not by downstream crates like yours. After removing the `_internal` attribute things should work. Tested with the following lib.rs:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate juniper;

mod model;
```

Comment: Thanks, I got to the same. But now when I try to use it like `RootNode::new(
            Database::new(),
            EmptyMutation::<Database>::new(),
    );` I got error: the trait `juniper::GraphQLType` is not implemented for `model::Database`;

Comment: @dtolnay jup, thanks for jumping in here. The _internal attribute is a hack to make the derives, defined in the juniper_codegen crate, work inside the main juniper crate (neccessary for fixing the input paths used).

Comment: @rofrol if you still have issues, feel free to ask on Gitter, I'm available tonight.